# ETCS with "element" as a primitive concept

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

In *[Rethinking set theory](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6543v1.pdf)* Tom Leinster writes:

> We could adapt the axiomatization in Section 2
>   by adding ‘element’ to the list of primitive concepts.

Assume we do so, that is, we add a relation symbol $\in$ to our formal system. Recall that in ETCS, there are the types "set" and "function between a set A and a set B". **Between which types is $\in$ a relation?**

My thoughts: The thing written to the right of $\in$ should be of type "set". But the thing written to the left of $\in$ can be of an arbitrary type: For functions $f: A\longrightarrow B$ we want to write $f\in B^A$, but we also want to write things like $\emptyset\in \{\emptyset\}$. So we cannot decide which type should be written to the left of $\in$. That is why I also ask the following question: In many-sorted first-order theories (that is first-order theories that are typed, that is, have types), is one allowed to have a relation between objects of any type? Or, when we have a relation $R(x, y)$, do we have to specify which type $x$ should have and which type $y$ should have?

Comment: In ETCS, we *don't* want to write things like $\varnothing \in \{ \varnothing\}$, assuming you mean $\varnothing$ to be an initial object (a.k.a. empty set). The singleton constructor is a natural transformation $A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$, not a function from the universe to itself like it is in ZFC.

Answer (score 1):

Note that membership is really just the evaluation function $e: X \times 2^X \to 2$ in ETCS.

It is the case that in many-sorted first-order logic, the relation symbols are expected to have a sort specified for each argument. However, I don't believe ETCS is intended to have a sort for every set, because that would make the language uncountable. [McLarty's formal presentation of ETCS](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/1998-February/001132.html) has just two sorts, one for objects and one for morphisms. The [presentation by Trimble and others](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fully+formal+ETCS) is single-sorted (morphisms only).

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP might be confusing ETCS with the internal logic of a topos.